# Plotting Survival Rates For Different Cohorts

Tags: data-visualization, survival, stata

I am using Stata 13 to analyze a panel with firm level data. I am estimating a dynamic probit model via the means of xtprobit. During my research I came across Peters (2009) and a very cool graph (see attachment) that I would like to mimic. The graph shows the survival rate for different cohorts.

I have searched the help function and the forum to see how this would be done - yet, I have found no answer so far. My idea is the following:

```
clear matrix
clear

    set more off

        use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/drug2.dta

            gen group=.
                replace group=1 if studytime <=10
                replace group=2 if studytime >10 & studytime <=20
                replace group=3 if studytime >20

            stset studytime

                sts graph if studytime , survival by(group)
                graph save survial.gph, replace
```

I think it goes into the right direction, but obviously it is far away from what I would like to mimic...
Any ideas how to do this?

PS: I crossposted this question at statalist here http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1294401-plotting-survival-rates-|-starting-each-period

**References**

Peters, B. (2009). Persistence of innovation: stylised facts and panel data evidence. The Journal of Technology Transfer, 34(2), 226-243.

[image]

Comment: Good question. But, there is something amiss in the chart, why do you have to have X axis label and legend telling you same thing, you could eliminate either one of them, in this case I would eliminate the legend. Alternatively, one could index all years and have a common start year as 1, 2 and so on ... and have the legend.

Comment: That's true. Elimanating the legend is of no issue code wise and indeed makes sense. However, getting this graph in the first place is where I fail. Any ideas?